# write string 0'-1" into sqlite android database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert, double-quotes

I cant seem to get this right so I am asking what am I overlooking in my code. here's what I've got in my code:

```
newLeaseData = "INSERT INTO " + enterLogLN + " (Date, "
            + "StockTank1Ft, StockTank1Inch, StockTank2Ft, StockTank2Inch, "
            + "StockTank3Ft, StockTank3Inch, StockTank4Ft, StockTank4Inch, "
            + "Change1, Change2, Change3, Change4) VALUES " 
            + "(" + today + ", '" + valueT1Ft + "', '" + valueT1Inch + "', '" + valueT2Ft 
            + "', '" + valueT2Inch + "', '" + valueT3Ft + "', '" + valueT3Inch 
            + "', '" + valueT4Ft + "', '" + valueT4Inch + "', " + difTotalT1 
            + ", " + difTotalT2 + ", " + difTotalT3 + ", " + difTotalT4 + ")";
```

everything works until I get to strings: difTotalT1, difTotalT2, difTotalT3 and difTotalT4.
each string is set to something like: 0'-1" , 0'-2" , 0'-3" or 0'-4"
and when I try to exec the command:

```
myDataBase.execSQL(EnterLogDataOilActivity.newLeaseData);
```

my app crashes with this logcat error:

06-05 04:36:23.824: E/AndroidRuntime(1127): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "'-1", 0'": syntax error: INSERT INTO about (Date, StockTank1Ft, StockTank1Inch, StockTank2Ft, StockTank2Inch, StockTank3Ft, StockTank3Inch, StockTank4Ft, StockTank4Inch, Change1, Change2, Change3, Change4) VALUES ('05_05_12', '0', '1', '0', '2', '0', '3', '0', '4', 0'-1", 0'-2", 0'-3", 0'-4")

thanks for the help I know it has got to be something simple. I have also tried inclosing each difTotalT1 string with a single quote but that does not work either (ie difTotalT1 = "'" + difTotalT1 + "'";)

this is the string I used to create the table in sqlite:

```
newLeaseTable = "create table '" + leaseName + "' (_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + " Date TEXT, StockTank1Ft NUMERIC, StockTank1Inch NUMERIC,"
            + " StockTank2Ft NUMERIC, StockTank2Inch NUMERIC, StockTank3Ft NUMERIC,"
            + " StockTank3Inch NUMERIC, StockTank4Ft NUMERIC, StockTank4Inch NUMERIC,"
            + " Change1 TEXT, Change2 TEXT, Change3 TEXT, Change4 TEXT, User TEXT);";
```

Comment: Try escaping the single quote and double quote \' and \"

Comment: it still gives me the same logcat error

Comment: Can you make an edit to your question and paste the structure of the table 'enterLogLN'

Comment: Consider using [`insert`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) so that you don't have to mess around with string wrangling to build your SQL.

Comment: I thought I am using the insert command, sorry I am new to sqlite

Comment: I mean the `insert` method that Android's SQLite API provides, follow the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work so I changed my var from a string to an int and then set it up so it would display it differently. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

try following way,

```
String singleQuote = "'";
char doubleQuote = '"';
```

Now concatenate your variable with the above variable as follows

```
String Change3 = "0" + singleQuote + "-3" + doubleQuote;  // result = 0'-3" in variable
```

Comment: okey, will be back with updated answer, with another option :)

Comment: do you mean for me to just add strings together ie: string AAAA = "a" string BBBB = "b" string CCCC = "c" so string DDDD = AAAA + BBBB + CCCC + DDDD to get: abc

Comment: yes, by concatenation it is possible, it is bit long process actually

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12139/discussion-between-deerkiller11-and-lucifer)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape quotes with backslashes, i.e.

```
difTotal = "0\\\'-1\\\"";
```

This results in difTotal being "0\'-1\"" when you use it to insert into MySQL.